# Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null. React Native Firebase app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am developing react native app using firebase.
When I run the app, build carried out successfully, but the issue occurs when I installing app on emulator. there are node modules in my app following as:

"dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
"@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.2",
"@react-native-community/google-signin": "^4.0.3",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.0.1",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^7.0.2",
"axios": "^0.19.2",
"base-64": "^0.1.0",
"firebase": "^7.8.2",
"formik": "^2.1.4",
"native-base": "^2.13.8",
"qs": "^6.9.3",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-app-intro-slider": "4.0.4",
"react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.3.2",
"react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
"react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "1.7.0",
"react-native-get-random-values": "^1.3.1",
"react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
"react-native-ionicons": "4.6.5",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-looped-carousel": "^0.1.13",
"react-native-media-controls": "^2.0.1",
"react-native-modal": "11.5.6",
"react-native-modal-loader": "^1.3.0",
"react-native-modalbox": "2.0.0",
"react-native-modals": "^0.19.9",
"react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.1.8",
"react-native-pixel-perfect": "^1.0.2",
"react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
"react-native-responsive-ui": "^2.1.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
"react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
"react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
"react-native-stars": "^1.2.1",
"react-native-svg": "^11.0.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"react-native-video": "^4.4.5",
"react-native-video-player": "^0.10.0",
"react-native-webview": "^9.2.0",
"react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.4",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.1",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0",
"react-navigation-transitions": "^1.0.12",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"yup": "^0.28.1"
},

[image]

Answer (score 1):

have you tried installing pods first?

First go to ios directory by

```
cd ios/
```

and then

```
pod install
```

Then try again rebuilding the project and start it in emulator.